# Messed up meshes

Tags: unity

I had this blender model imported to unity.
And then export to android studio as library.

The exported model meshes messed up in emulator while in game player everything look great.
Can anyone help to find where the problem is.

Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an artifact called "Z-Fighting" — especially if you see these patterns flicker and shimmer when the camera makes small movements.

It occurs when you don't have enough precision in your depth buffer to reliably distinguish which of two close-together polygons is in front. So, depending on which way each pixel's depth value gets rounded, you get alternating speckles/stripes/triangles of one surface poking through another.

This is usually because your camera's near plane and far plane are too far apart. The available bits in your depth buffer need to be stretched out to fill the whole gap from near to far, which means each pattern "bucket" ends up spanning a wider range of depths.

Since you seem to have a very up-close view in this part of your game, try bringing your far plane in very close — just far away enough that it doesn't clip your character. You should see the precision improve greatly and the Z-Fighting should be replaced with correctly-sorted surfaces.

Other things you can do include editing the model so there's a bigger gap between parallel surfaces, so they're less likely to get rounded to the same depth, or editing your shader/material to add a depth bias or always-on-top rendering behaviour to the overlaid item.

Comment: Hi, i tried to set the plane far to half of it, but the model disappear. Do you mind to make a private chat?

Comment: My problem is that the model is under the canvas, just move it out from the canvas will do.

Comment: In future, please remember to include important details like "I put my mesh inside a canvas" in the body of your question. You'll get working answers faster that way.